# tap recogniser is not working on moving image view

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

[image] my code is that....full scenario is that the ballon is flying on the screen when I tapped on the balloon so the ballon is blast.... but when I add the tap recogniser to blast the ballon so that is not working on the moving balloon. when I stable the balloon and apply tap recogniser so its working...

Comment: Please share the code what you have tried so far

Comment: check this maybe can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45001668/how-to-drag-certain-image-in-ios/45002245#45002245

Comment: I add the screen shot of my code.... I am new in IOS help me

Comment: How do you animate the ballon? You might animate the layer of the button but the frame is not moved, try to tap in the place where the ballon first appears and see if the method is called. If it's called you have a problem with the animation of the ballon.

Comment: I am sure that doing  moving also frame...

Comment: Why not just use a UIButton?